# Get count of product under a sub-category as well as total count of the main category from the sub-categories

Tags: laravel, count, categories, parent

If there products in a child category, I want to count all products in the parent category of that child category.
for example:

1. Category1 (Total Product 10) // how I can get it

   - Category 1.1 (Total Product 5)
   - Category 1.2 (Total Product 3)
   - Category 1.3 (Total Product 2)

Json Code:

```
id: 291,
    level: 1,
    parent_id: null, //parent category
    name: "Chemicals",
    bn_name: null,
    sector: "product",
    slug: "Chemicals",
    status: "active",
    created_at: "2021-04-16T23:53:52.000000Z",
    updated_at: "2021-04-16T23:53:52.000000Z",
    **products_count: 0,**
    total_items: 1,
    sub_categories: [
    
    id: 292,
    level: 2,
    parent_id: 291,
    name: "Activated Carbon",
    bn_name: null,
    sector: "product",
    slug: "Activated-Carbon",
    status: "active",
    created_at: "2021-04-16T23:53:52.000000Z",
    updated_at: "2021-04-16T23:53:52.000000Z",
    products_count: 0,
    total_items: 0,
    sub_categories: [ ]
    },
    {
    id: 293,
    level: 2,
    parent_id: 291,
    name: "Adhesives & Sealants",
    bn_name: null,
    sector: "product",
    slug: "Adhesives-&-Sealants",
    status: "active",
    created_at: "2021-04-16T23:53:52.000000Z",
    updated_at: "2021-04-16T23:53:52.000000Z",
    products_count: 0,
    total_items: 0,
    sub_categories: [ ]
    },
    {
    id: 294,
    level: 2,
    parent_id: 291,
    name: "Agro Chemicals",  //child category
    bn_name: null,
    sector: "product",
    slug: "Agro-Chemicals",
    status: "active",
    created_at: "2021-04-16T23:53:52.000000Z",
    updated_at: "2021-04-16T23:53:52.000000Z",
    **products_count: 1,**
    total_items: 1,
    sub_categories: [ ]
}
```

Controller Code is:

```
return $categories = Category::rootCategories()->with('subCategories')->withCount('products')->orderBy('name', 'ASC')->get();
```

Category Models:

```
public static function rootCategories() {
    return self::whereNull('parent_id')->where('status', 'active')->orderBy('name', 'ASC');
}

public static function productRootCategories() {
    return self::whereNull('parent_id')->where(['status' => 'active', 'sector' => 'product'])->orderBy('name', 'asc');
}

public function subCategories() {
    return $this->hasMany(self::class, 'parent_id')->where('status', 'active')->with('subCategories')->withCount('products')->orderBy('name', 'asc');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this in two way.

1. Just change your database relationship just a little by adding category_id column in products table and just specify the category when you add new products. It's the simplest and easiest way cause when you want to count all products of a category just add hasMany function in Category Model to get easily like-

   ```
   public function products()
   {
    return $this->hasMany(Product::class);
   }
   ```

   and add belongsTo function in Product Model -

   ```
   public function category()
   {
    return $this->belongsTo(Category::class);
   }
   ```

   You're setted up, now call in controller like this -

   ```
    use App\Models\Category;

    $category = Category::find(your_category_id);
    $category_products = count($category->products);
   ```

   ***It's done and simple.***
2. If you don't have category column in product table and if you have already added a large data in product table then use eloquent collection and foreach loop like this to count the products-

   First add hasMany function in Category model for subcategories -

   ```
   public function subCategories()
   {
    return $this->hasMany(SubCategory::class);
   }
   ```

   And then belogsTo function in SubCategory Model for categories -

   ```
   public function category()
    {
      return $this->belongsTo(Category::class);
    }
   ```

   And also add hasMany function in SubCategory for products defining subcategory_id -

   ```
    public function products()
    {
      return $this->hasMany(Product::class, 'subcategory_id');
    }
   ```

   Done! Now use this method in controller to get the products by your category and count them.

   ```
    $category = Category::findOrFail(your_category_id);

    $result = array();
    foreach ($category->subCategories as $key => $sub) {
        array_push($result, $sub->products->toArray());
    }

    $products = call_user_func_array('array_merge', $result);
    return count($products);
   ```

   And If you also want to get all categories data then use like this -

   ```
    $data = array();
    $categories = Category::all();
    foreach ($categories as $category) {
        $result = array();
        foreach ($category->subCategories as $key => $sub) {
            array_push($result, $sub->products->toArray());
        }

        $products = call_user_func_array('array_merge', $result);
        $data[$category->id] = count($products);
    }

    return $data;
   ```

   ***Now you will get the total product count :)***

Comment: thank you for your response... i have category_id column in product list...
i will not $category = Category::find(your_category_id); because, i want all categories data..

Comment: using loop will not reduce number of queries brother.... i had done with it before.. but i want less queries. Thanks

Comment: Yup! That's true. But also you can shorten the code by using the logic

Comment: i understand. Thank you. You Tried to helpme.